# getWidth() function in bitmap library of android doesn't return true image height

Tags: android, width, renderscript, android-bitmap

I wanted to load an .PNG image through my android application by using android.graphics.Bitmap library. I have succeeded to load it but there is some problem i can't figure out.

My image pixel count is 144*144 but when i try to get the width of my loaded image by using getWidth() function, it returns 432 which is 144*3.

This is how i try to load my image:

```
mBitmapIn = loadBitmap(R.drawable.data);
```

Where the loadBitmap function is defined as:

```
private Bitmap loadBitmap(int resource) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource, options);
}
```

I would appreciate if anybody could help me to find out the reason of it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code that you're using to load the image and call getWidth()?

Comment: I have posted the code in my question,thanks

Comment: are you trying to load the image from the android res folders? If so are you storing your bitmap in the `mdpi` folder and the actual device/emulator you are using works with `xxhdpi` resolution?

Comment: I am using Android Studio which there is only one folder for drawables called _drawable_  , and also i am using the default adb which is nexus 5 that has screen resolution of 1920*1080.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawable` folder is considered to have `mdpi`'s density (which is the baseline density). Nexus 5 has a density of 445ppi which falls under `xxhdpi` category. Therefore if you read in a bitmap which is not present in `drawable-xxhdpi` directory, the system will have to find it in another directory and scale it. `xxhdpi` screens are approximately 3 times as dense as `mdpi` screens. Since the only drawable folder you have under `res` is `drawable` itself, android scales it 3 times along both the dimensions

You can get more information about this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, I wanted to ask another question if it's possible: When i try to load an image with resolution of 2560*1440 the application crashes and it does not even start, is the problem again with my folder directories? ( The image is again in drawable folder, and also my application is using renderscript and i'm trying to allocate my image for some image processing) Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with `renderscript`, but I may have some ideas as to why your app is crashing. You say that you load a 2560 x 1440 image from the `drawable` folder. Android will scale up the image for Nexus 5 (3 times). Therefore the image will be 7680 x 4320 in resolution which equates to 33177600 pixels. Considering the case that each pixels takes 32 bits (8 for each of red, green, blue & alpha channels) to read in the bitmap you should have at least 1061683200 bits = 126.5625 MB. If the system can't find a single block of free memory which is ~127MB in size, the app crashes with OOM error